# UISwipeGestureRecognizer gesture start point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

Is it possible to get a gesture start point from a UISwipeGestureRecognizer. like how its possible in

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [UISwipeGestureRecognizer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can:

> You may determine the location where a swipe began by calling the UIGestureRecognizer methods locationInView: and locationOfTouch:inView:. The former method gives you the centroid if more than one touch was involved in the gesture; the latter gives the location of a particular touch.

PS: you really should first look at the documentation, the answer was in the class reference of UISwipeGestureRecognizer, shouldn't be hard to find. Part of being a developer is being able to look things up, Apple has excellent documentation, use it!

Answer (score 4):

**WARNING**

Amy's answer is totally **INCORRECT!** Recognizer may generate `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` but on swipe `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` generates `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` event only.

But `touchesBegan:` works instead. The problem is if it supports user interaction then it works for current view only and you need to pass it to a parent view.

Comment: Once you have enough [reputation to vote posts down](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), use that method to vote down posts you think are not useful. Your answer should simply be used to answer the question as you see fit.

Comment: I wanted to reply but: `You must have 50 reputation to comment`. Your vote down: `Awarded At: 125 Reputation`. So should I shut up even if I see such a rude mistake?

Comment: If you see an incorrect answer, you should provide a correct one instead, if that has not already been done. Correct answers generally gain upvotes, which will eventually get you to the reputation you need to comment or downvote. Alternatively, if the answer isn't too far from being correct, you can modify it to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. See code below:

```
if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [recognizer state] != UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    NSLog(@"StateBegan :::::");
}
```

Comment: There was a conditional mistake. Well it is good now. Vote up!!